# Infill datetime index with all dates

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe with various dates and that dates equivalent value.

I would like to have, however, a dataframe whereby every day is accounted for and the empty day infills with previous values.

So at present I have

```
            Value
01/01/2013  23
09/01/2013  43
13/01/2013  12
19/01/2013  35
```

and I would like:

```
            Value
01/01/2013  23
02/01/2013  23
03/01/2013  23
04/01/2013  23
05/01/2013  23
06/01/2013  23
07/01/2013  23
08/01/2013  23
09/01/2013  43
10/01/2013  43
11/01/2013  43
12/01/2013  43
13/01/2013  12
14/01/2013  12
15/01/2013  12
16/01/2013  12
17/01/2013  12
18/01/2013  12
19/01/2013  35
```

Comment: If you have a DatetimeIndex, then `df.resample('D').ffill()`.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you stuck? Like, do you know about [resampling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#resampling)?

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.resample` would be the right move here.

> Resample time-series data.
>
> Convenience method for frequency conversion and resampling of time
> series. The object must have a datetime-like index (DatetimeIndex,
> PeriodIndex, or TimedeltaIndex), or the caller must pass the label of
> a datetime-like series/index to the on/level keyword parameter.
> https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html

a basic example could look like this:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv("dat.csv", sep=";", header=None)
# first we turn the index of our dataframe into a DatetimeIndex
df.set_index(0, inplace=True)
df.index = pandas.to_datetime(df.index, format="%d/%m/%Y")
# Now we fill up the Index the missing Days and its Values
df = df.resample("D").ffill()
```

---

example dat.csv

```
01/01/2013; 23
09/01/2013; 43
13/01/2013; 12
19/01/2013; 35
```

Comment: It's easier to have `read_csv` handle all the setup for you: `parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, index_col=0`.

Comment: Also, why did you bother using a separator besides comma and removing the header? If you just use commas and slap `,Value` on the top, the example is simpler *and* matches the question.

Comment: I see, i like the `df=pandas.read_csv("dat.csv", parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True, index_col=0)` and  `,Value ` idea. It indeed makes everything smoother.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already your dataframe, like you said in your description, it could look like:

```py
import pandas as pd

original_values = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Value': [23, 43, 12,35]},
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-01-01', '2013-01-09', '2013-01-13', '2013-01-19'])
)

output_values = original_values.resample('D').ffill()

print(output_values)
```

But if your values come from a CSV file like:

**Input_data.csv**

```
01/01/2013, 23
09/01/2013, 43
13/01/2013, 12
19/01/2013, 35
```

You could then use something like that to have the same outcome:

```py
import pandas as pd

original_values = pd.read_csv(
    'Input_data.csv', 
    header=None,
    names=['Date', 'Value'],
    index_col='Date', 
    parse_dates=True, 
    date_format='%d/%m/%Y'
)

output_values = original_values.resample('D').ffill()

print(output_values)
```